How to select browser in Power Automate?
I have a power automate flow that makes Facebook group posts. When the Facebook account used gets a notification, the page title changes by adding a (1) to the Facebook tab name in the browser. So it’ll be like “(1) Facebook Group 1”.
This (1) breaks the flow until I manually clear those notifications.
What’s a better way to select that window everytime I need to in the flow?

You have various options:

Click the required tab dynamically by registering the tab with (1) added and continue the workflow
Append the current browser name with (1) and pass it as execution parameter
Creating another browser session after the previous action is complete. Add a wait time so that previous items are properly loaded so that you will always have a tab with (1) to initiate the next process.
Trigger a new tab on existing browser by URL from the previous one. This will start the (1) tab without having to be dependent upon the tab name. This works for all variations in tab names.
You can also create a UI journey from desktop by adding and configuring button clicks only so that your flow ends up at the required browser for further operations. This will be affected if the UI journey is disturbed and the flow may fail.

